# RhoMobile LOV (List Of Values)

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

Does anyone know how to implement a LOV (List Of Values) search in an RhoMobile Application?
I need to put a field with the customer's code, where the user can find the code by typing the name of the customer, that is one of more than a thousand of possible values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean searching the local database on the device, see the Rhom (Rhodes' ORM) reference here: http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/Rhom#find.28.2Aargs.29

If you mean searching some backend web service directly from your Rhodes that depends on the web service that you connect to.

If you mean syncing a subset of information from a backend web service based on multiple criteria with RhoSync (syncing a subset of data) that is the async search call: http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/RhodesConnectToWebServices#Asynchronous_search_call

Comment: I asked how to search in the local database (first answer), but when I have asked I did not know how to create the screen or panel to show the filters and the results of the searching. But now I have already learned how to do this. I am using JQuery.
However, thanks.

Comment: Can you share your solution to the problem?